# Doing a course on Code HS, errors say "Bad operator types for binary operator" for lines with the public void. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java

**EXERCISE DIRECTIONS**

In this exercise, you must take your Fraction class
from earlier and extend it by adding a few handy methods.

```
public void add(Fraction other)
public void subtract(Fraction other)
public void multiply(Fraction other)
public int getNumerator();
public int getDenominator();
public void setNumerator(int x);
public void setDenominator(int x);
public String toString();
```

Use the FractionTester file to test as you go along.

Note that

```
public void add(Fraction other)
public void subtract(Fraction other)
public void multiply(Fraction other)
```

are void methods. They do not return anything. These methods should not create a new Fraction and return it.

Instead, these methods should modify the instance variables to be added, subtracted, or multiplied by the Fraction other.

For example, the following code:

```
Fraction first = new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction second = new Fraction(1, 3);
System.out.println();

System.out.println("BEFORE:");
System.out.println("first: " + first);
System.out.println("second: " + second);

first.multiply(second);

System.out.println("AFTER:");

System.out.println("first: " + first);
System.out.println("second: " + second);
```

Should print out:

BEFORE:
first: 1 / 2
second: 1 / 3

AFTER:
first: 1 / 6
second: 1 / 3
The Fraction first was modified by being multiplied by the Fraction second. first was affected, second was not. 1/2 became 1/6 because it was multiplied by 1/3.

**This is my code:**

```
public class Fraction
{
    // Create your instance variables and constructor here

    //Instance variables
    private int num;
    private int den;

    //Constructor
    public Fraction(int nume, int dene)
    {
        num = nume;
        den = dene;
    }


    public void add(Fraction other) 
    {
        Fraction a = num/den + other;
    }

    public void subtract(Fraction other) 
    {
        Fraction b = num/den - other;
    }

    public void multiply(Fraction other) 
    {
        Fraction c = num/den * other;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just multiply by the fraction instance. You need to derefence the num and den.

Comment: Strip out all the parts of the question that aren't necessary to produce that specific error. See [mre] guidelines -- as also described in [How Do I Ask And Answer Homework Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) in the guidance to ask about *a problem you encountered while doing* your homework, instead of asking about your homework itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply an `int` (e.g. den or num) directly by a `Fraction` object.  You need to `dereference` the passed fraction argument and then update the `den` and `num` components of the `calling instance`.

This

```
public void multiply(Fraction other)  {
        Fraction c = num/den * other;
 }
```

Needs to be replaced with this.

```
public void multiply(Fraction other)  {
        num = num * other.num;
        den = den * other.den;
 }
```

When you add or subtract, you need to find common denominators.

Comment: Thank you! This did work, and I was able to figure out the add and subtract methods.